# Adding .lib file in tasks.json in Visual Studio Code IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am setting up a projet using Visual Studio Code in Windows10 . Following are my queries

1. **if I want to link with a static lib, in which format that I should give in tasks.json file**

I am using rest api package in the following way

"-IC:\Nuget\cpprestsdk.v.141.2.10.7\installed\x64-windows\include\cpprest",
"-LC:\Nuget\cpprestsdk.v.141.2.10.7\installed\x64-windows\lib",
"brotlicommon.lib",
"-lbrotlidec",
"-lcpprest_2_10"
....

is it ok to give the path setting in the above way.

2 **What is the format to give include path in c_cpp_properties.json**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.